# How to Reset form field after submit in HTMX

Tags: django, htmx

I'm tried to reset form field after submit the data in HTMX.
Please guide me how to do.

Comment: You can send back a new empty form after the submit. Could you share an example form and view endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with with htmx beforeswap https://htmx.org/docs/#modifying_swapping_behavior_with_events

To make the example below work django view must return HttpResponse(status=204)

```
htmx.on("htmx:beforeSwap", (e) => {
        if (!e.detail.xhr.response) {
            var title = $('#id_title');
            if (title) {
                title.val('');
            }
        }
    })
```

Tutorial how to work with django forms and htmx https://blog.benoitblanchon.fr/django-htmx-modal-form/